# Translation suggestion of an operation - adding and subtracting the same term - German: Nullergänzung

Tags: notation, definition, reference-works

How would one call this operation in English where we add a term $a$ and subtract the additive inverse $-a$ right away again, so
$$
f(x)-g(x)=f(x)-a+a-g(x)
$$
for example here where we also use the triangle inequality 
$$
|x|= |(x + y)−y|\leq|x+y|+|y|\iff |x| − |y| \leq |x + y|
$$
where we added and subtracted $y$.

I just couldn't find a proper translation, in German one would call it for example ***nahrhafte Null*** or ***Nullergänzung*** which literally means *nutritious zero* and *zero completion/addition* respectively, though I have never read those translations anywhere, ever.

Other languages might also be interesting but I am mostly interested in English. Are there any dictionaries out there which mainly focus on mathematical terminology?

Comment: i would write Zero Addition  this is the nearest word to German Nulladdition

Comment: I have often called this (and heard it be called) "adding a zero", so one uses a verb to describe doing the procedure.

Comment: @s.harp by any chance, have you any reference at hand?

Comment: I have perhaps heard it called a few different things, but there isn't a great term in English for it afaik. I would stick with "add and subtract $a$" or something of the like. If I needed to explain my process in a paper. In my mind, ***clarity >> brevity***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a great teacher in high school, named John Titterton. He called this a "propitious zero." When multiplying and dividing by the same thing, he called it a "propitious one."   My guess is that he invented these phrases himself. They work well.

[image]

Comment: I go with that! It's funny how much the terminology deviates from language to language - it's a quite common wording in German, every school child knows this (or at least should).